# What is the name of metal-metal junction?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, conductors, electronic-band-theory, metals

When two different metals come in contact, a junction at their contact is created.
What is the name of that junction?

Comment: As far as I know, you've answered your own question in the title.  I've never heard a better name for them; anything used would probably be industry/field specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a metal-metal contact or junction. You use them, e.g., in thermo-couples. There are no other special designations for electrical contacts between metals. There are many for mechanical connections.

Comment: in the transistor world, that's called a schottky junction.

Comment: @niels_nielsen that would be a metal-semiconductor junction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_barrier